# Display the content of a PDF File in a Text Field

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am newbie in Oracle Forms. I have stored a PDF file in an Oracle database; now I want to read that PDF file and display the content in text field in Oracle Forms.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: You want to show file in form or just open for users to see?

Comment: JUST OPEN FOR USER TO SEE THE FILE

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Forms cannot natively display a PDF.  If you are storing the actual contents of the PDF in the database, you can look into developing a PJC that leverages an existing Open Source PDF presentation layer, and embed it in the Oracle Form.  You would then need to stream the contents of the database into the PJC, which would be tricky (but not impossible).

Your better bet would be to build a small PL/SQL package that can be accessed from a DAD to serve up the document, and fire off a web.show_document call to the URL from Oracle Forms.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in to do this.
But if you dont have to use the content of the PDF anywhere
i.e you just want to see the contents of the PDF then you may try this :  ( **webutil utility required)

```
vboolean :=  webutil_file_transfer.DB_To_Client_With_Progress
                        ( 'D:\files\abc.pdf' ,  --location of the file with extension
                          'table_nm',  --table name 
                          'field_nm', --field which contains ur PDF
                          'sr_no=1' , --fetch the PDF of row where sr_no =1
                          'Downloading from Database',
                          'Wait to Complete');
client_host('cmd /c start '||vfilename1); --open the file
```

If you want to make it generic, you can store the extention, append it to the file_nm i.e 
1st parameter of DB_To_Client_With_Progress(), then you will be able to open any type of document stored in the database!